# javascript adding up numbers in sequence returns incorrect number when big numbers are passed

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, gauss

So I was trying to compare the two functions and I realized that when you pass `1000000000` as `n` to both functions they don't return the same value, even though they should. The sum function returns `500000000067109000` when the correct answer is `500000000500000000`.
Why is this happening?

```js
function sum(n) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  return sum
}

function sum2(n) {
  return n * (n + 1) / 2
}

console.log(sum(1000000000)); //returns 500000000067109000 (incorrect)
console.log(sum2(1000000000)); //returns 500000000500000000 (correct)
```

Comment: also I wrote the same functions in python and they worked as expected.

Comment: Your number is too big to represent accurately. Since you are working with integers, I suggest using [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER